# Oracle Apex Layout - child element sticking out 

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

This is piece of reporting page I have to create. Unfortunately table has many columns and it sticks out from main region of page. I am using standard Apex theme  ( no6 - Centered Blue).
Could someone please advise how to modify css  so layout would be more responsive and white region at the back would stretch to be at the background of these to regions ?

How to find name of class/id of "white rounded element" in Apex?

Anyone giving answer in this topic would be life safer as deadline is approaching :)

[image: Report falling apart]

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebug or chrome developer tools to check the CSS of each element on the page.

On chrome press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to get the Developer Bar

On firefox you have to install firebug extension and then check the elements.

Also the white background behind must be having width set to a fixed number and hence it is not accommodating the change. You can either make the width of larger or remove that property.

You can see a working example here which will show you the difference between the 2 different widths of background div and overflow of foreground div: http://jsfiddle.net/shubhanshumishra/CCEmS/

Comment: If only formating elements would be that easy in Apex. Unfortunately I dont have access to source CSS files. I understand that I have to change overflow property of white region. Thx anyway.

Comment: The CSS files might not be alterable but you can inspect and edit the HTML and applied styles using developer tools in the browser in order to find a local - page or template level fix. There are attributes you can use in the report, the report template, the region the region template, etc.

Comment: For the time being I predefined width of region element to width="rediciolus_widthpx" however it means that this region is not flexible if report has less number of columns. If anyone come across better solution I would love to hear.